# Can I make a new dtype for numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very big numpy matrix. Luckily there are only 4 possible options for values in the matrix, let say 0,1,2,3. Now of course instead of using float32, I can set the type to int8, to save memory (and storage, later when I save it).

My values range is exactly 2 in the power of 2, so theoretically, I can use just 2 bits for each cell, and save about 4 times memory. Is it possible to give a specific number of bits for the dtype?

Ideally I would like to do something like:

`compressed_matrix = matrix.astype(np.int2)`

I know theoretically I can stuck few cells together, like:

```
for i in range(0,len(arr),4):

    comp_arr[i/4] = arr[i+3] + 4 * arr[i+2] + 16 * arr[i+1] + 64 * arr[i]
```

And later it will be possible to reconstruct it. But in the compressed form it will be very hard to apply operations on this array, such as transpose it, sum along axis, etc.. This solution might be good only for saving the matrix in the disk.

EDIT:

I add here some code example of usage. Let say `window0` and `window2` are 2 matrix that satisfy this condition. Both very big, with values in range 0 to 3, and both in the same shape).

We have as well vectors name `ref_freq` and `non_ref_freq`, which are floats vector in the range between 0 to 1, and are in the same len, defined by `ref_freq = 1 - non_ref_freq`.

My current code, which works, but not on very large matrix is:

```
first_element = (ref_freq * window0) @ window0.T
second_element = (non_ref_freq * (2 - window2)) @ (2 - window2).T
similarity = (first_element + second_element) / 4
np.fill_diagonal(similarity, 0)
```

Any idea that can help me?

Thanks,

Shahar

Comment: It will be more efficient in memory (volatile, and on disk), but unlikely to be more efficient in computation, unless you have a chip dedicated to 2-bit calculations. And on-disk storage can likely be compressed (afterwards), so that may not matter as well.

Comment: An improvement could be to use uint8.

Comment: Something like transpose might become a lot harder, but I bet you can figure out bit twiddling equivalents for a lot of other operations: possibly all the ones you care about.

Comment: So the question you could also ask is: do I need to this memory saving, or can I deal with more memory usage and straightforward NumPy usage?

Comment: @CozyCode I am not sure why uint8 will be an improvement

Comment: @MadPhysicist Unfortunately I need to transpose it, and use matrix multiplication later with a 0/1 matrix

Comment: @Shaq. Could you give a concrete example. It would be interesting to see if we could bit twiddle it. Without a concrete example, this is just speculation and therefore off topic.

Comment: @9769953 Saving storage is just a bonus, and computation efficiency is not a problem to me, (unless it will take significantly longer). My biggest problem is that I construct this matrix  of size 1000*10^7, and its too big for my RAM, so most important issue here is to save memory

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added an edit in the comment. But my problem is that I cannot even load `window0`. The perfect solution would be to construct it in a 'lighter ' data type

Comment: Writing a bunch of code to use a weird integer type seems like way more work and way less scalable than batching it (which is generally tractable for matrix multiplication problems).

Comment: @CJR I actually have this problem in 2 different places in the code, where solving only one of them will help a lot. In one place all I need is to transpose the matrix, and later I only use random access, no computations. Is there a way to transpose a matrix in batching using numpy? Can I hold a numpy object greater than my RAM (i.e using swaps? I am using Linux). Feeling like I have too many questions...

Comment: [Don't reinvent the "my data is too big for my memory" wheel](https://examples.dask.org/array.html)

Comment: AFAIK, no, you cannot use smaller data types than a byte: Numpy does not support that. That being said using a `int8`/`uint8` is already much better. You can avoid several temporary arrays to be created with *Numba* or *in-place computations*. This is important if you want to manually save some space using bit-packing.

Comment: The fastest `matmul` is with float dtypes. Int dtypes a bit slower.  Custom dtypes much slower.